# How can I measure the frequency of multiple square waves?

Tags: integrated-circuit, frequency, wave, square, meter

I'm trying to evaluate the frequency of 18 independent sources of square waves in my system (the signals are generated independently as feedback.) Basically, I need to have a way to use one microcontroller and poll all these frequency meters in order to have the frequencies for all the signals as fast as I can (lets say I need to have the same refresh rate for the entire system as the slowest of the signals.)

I have though of using a multiplexter and a TAB UFDC-1. It works but I have to wait for every signal to switch on the chip, be evaluated and then read.

Ideally I would put 18 of these chips, but their cost (14 pounds) makes it an impossible option.

Any other idea? Do you know any other IC or combination that would give me the same result?

The serial output is not really a requirement, but would make my life easier.

Comment: Several frequency to voltage circuits and an ADC? Or grab yourself a microcontroller suited for automotive use - they come with lots of timers - and measure each directly

Comment: How stationary will the signals be? What is the fmax. frequency, what the accuracy required? There are MCUs with quite a number of timers/counters (some with *capture* and/or *compare* capabilities); slow signals can be handled with interrupts or polls.

Comment: Is this something that can be sampled by a [logic analyzer](https://sigrok.org/wiki/Supported_hardware#Logic_analyzers)?  Maybe there is a model with 18+ frequency counters.

Comment: The rate at which the frequency will be changing is an important factor. If it's slow enough, you can multiplex and switch for long enough to get the rate.

Comment: `trying to evaluate the frequency of 18 independent sources of square waves in my system` Do you need that during development, only, or as part of system functionality? 
(FWIW: TAB UFDC-1 \$f_{max}\$ 120/7.5 MHz with/out prescaler.)

Comment: What is the maximum frequency of each input? The minimum frequency? 'As fast as I can' is not a specification, how soon do you need to respond to frequency changes? What resolution do you need? Taking the spec of the very capable UFDC may result in an impractical over-design for what you actually need. You may be able to get away with a single MCU, if your requirements are low enough, or bolster an MCU with some very cheap logic chips, if you can spell out your real performance requirements accurately.

Comment: So to clarify:
frequency spans from 25 Hz to 10kHz, and it is a system requirement that the frequency evaluation shall happen with a 20 Hz refresh rate.
It is a permanent, not development solution.
Last the signals can vary their frequency with a max acceleration of 25 to 25kHz in 4 seconds

Comment: Have a look at SN74LV8154, each chip contains 2 16 bit counters, that can be read using an 8 bit parallel interface. You can use them as gated counters and read and clear them with 20 Hz poll rate to measure the signal period times. They are not that expensive.

Comment: @Jens could i use the squared wave to be measured as gating signal and let it count while the signal is up and send it to a shift register as soon as the signal  to be measured goes down (ideally resetting the counter as well).
In this way i should always have the last read value in the shift register that i can read asynchronously